# Why is Sling ignoring the "adaptable" parameter of HTL's data-sly-use?

Tags: sling, sightly, htl, sling-models

In 2017 [functionality was added](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-6504) to Apache Sling and HTL to allow use of [the Use API](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scripting/scripting-htl.html) with a different adaptable (such as a resource resolver, or a child resource) rather than the default backing resource or request.

Feike Visser provided an example of [how to use such flexible adapters](https://github.com/heervisscher/htl-examples/blob/93666b5eebdeb36c25adf2e310f55049ec3767ce/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/aemhtlexamples/components/aem6.3/flexibleadaptable/example.html) with a simple list:

```
<div data-sly-list.child="${resource.listChildren}">
   <sly data-sly-use.c="${'com.adobe.examples.htl.core.models.HelloWorldModel' @ adaptable=child}" />
   ${c.resourceType}
</div>
```

However, the example does not appear to work (in this case, using non-AEM Sling 11). While the `HelloWorldModel` (a Sling Model) is instantiated, the backing resource is always the original page, not the adaptable specified. It's as it the `adaptable=child` part is ignored.

What might be preventing this useful feature from working?

EDIT: The `HelloWorldModel` is based on Visser's [example](https://github.com/heervisscher/htl-examples/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/examples/htl/core/models/HelloWorldModel.java):

```
@Model(adaptables=Resource.class)
public class HelloWorldModel {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorldModel.class);

    @OSGiService
    private SlingSettingsService settings;

    @SlingObject
    private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

    @ValueMapValue(name = "sling:resourceType", injectionStrategy=InjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL) @Default(values="No resourceType")
    private String resourceType;

    private String message;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("Reached init of HelloWorldModel");
        message = "\tHello World!\n";
        message += "\tResource type is: " + resourceType + "\n";
        message += "\tUser id is " + resourceResolver.getUserID() + "\n";
    }

    public String getResourceType() {
           return resourceType;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        log.info("Inside getMessage() method");
        return message;
    }  
}
```

The output is always the resource type of the page resource, never the resource type of the list children.

EDIT: Could this be because the `SlingModelsUseProvider` is used before the `JavaUseProvider`, meaning that the `JavaUseProvider` - which provides the flexible adaptation - is never reached?

Comment: Can you show the model?

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic It's based on the `HelloWorldModel` in Visser's example. Have added above.

Comment: could you check the resource types of the children an preferably post the JSON of the including resources (under `cq:PageContent`).

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic The resource types are my own custom types e.g. `spinner/parent` and `spinner/child`. Since I'm in a non-AEM environment, there aren't any resources under `cq:PageContent`.

Comment: Is there a workaround that allows adaptation of the list children with a specified model class?